# When using bind() to pass an argument to event handler in React component, what is the argument and "this" referring to within the event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

I am a newbie who just started studying React.

I am very confused with `bind()` method that is used within `onClick` inside the component tag.

Below is the snippet of my code. This code works, but I am not really sure what bind() is doing and how is it working.

When I click the button, I am passing "Jack" as the argument of `switchNameHandler` method.

When the `switchNameHandler` is executed, what is inside the argument `newName`?
And what are `this` referring to inside the `switchNameHandler` method and `bind(this, 'Jack')` line? What exactly is `bind(this, 'Jack')` doing?

```
...
switchNameHandler = (newName) => {
 this.setState({
  persons: [
    {name: newName, age: 21},
     ]
    });
  }

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, 'Jack')}>Switch Name</button>
    <Person 
      name={this.state.persons[0].name} 
      age={this.state.persons[0].age}></Person>
   </div>
    );
  }
...
```

Comment: Since you are actually using the arrow function for switchNameHandler. Please try by removing bind?

Answer (score 0):

1. Paste `console.log(newName)` in your switchNameHandler function before **this.setState** -> it should print some info in devtool -> console
2. Some info about bind(): https://javascript.info/bind